# Como capturo el valor de un nodo en javascript para hacer un filtro en un menu, de acuerdo al texto capturado del nodo

Tags: javascript

```js
const optionsFilter = document.getElementById("selection");

optionsFilter.addEventListener("click",() =>{

    let condition = optionsFilter.children;

    for (i=0;i<condition.length;i++){
        console.log(condition[i].text);
    }

    
    


});
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" id="selection">

                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bug</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dragon</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Electric</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fighting</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fire</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bug</a>
                                </div>
```

lo que quiero es capturar el valor del texto del a para realizar un filtro de acuerdo a ese valor, accedo a el pero no se como capturarlo cuando el usuario haga clic en la elección respectiva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas capturar el evento y desplegar el `text` del `target` asi:

```js
const optionsFilter = document.getElementById("selection");

optionsFilter.addEventListener("click",(e) =>{

    console.log(e.target.text);  
  
});
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" id="selection">

                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bug</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dragon</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Electric</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fighting</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fire</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bug</a>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono, saludos

Comment: @NohemiMartinez marca correcta la pregunta